# In a Zend/MYSQL search, join a table with a requirement of NO results from that join

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, join, left-join

I'm using Zend (v1) and have a search query that primarily searches a "locations" table. For the sake of this example, these are event venues/locations. All is great with the world with this query until...

I need an option to search "availability" as well. There is a separate "events" table that stores event details for all the locations, including the dates of the events. Having no results from the "events" table during a given timeframe means that location available (i.e. no events scheduled).

So, I essentially need to search a joined table **that returns no results from that join**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.location_id = l.location_id
  AND e.date >= '$start_date'
  AND e.date <= '$end_date'
WHERE e.location_id IS NULL
```

Basically you're putting what would normally be the where conditions into the left join on events and then in your where have the IS NULL on some events column that would only be NULL if there was no event.